# Cannot debug ASP.NET MVC in localhost anymore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localhost, visual-studio-debugging

Suddenly I cannot debug my ASP.NET MVC 4 WebApp on localhost anymore, it always starts in `http://www.domain.com` instead of `http://localhost:49688/`.

I created a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project to see if I could reproduce the problem but in this case it debugs properly on `http://localhost:49688/`.

I also checked the project settings one by one and they are all the same.

I also restored a few previous versions from source control to be sure that the culprit were not the latest modifications.

What else should I check?

I am using VStudio 2013 SP4. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked Project Url on the Web tab?

Comment: Please make sure that another application on same port of your application is not running on the machine and also check that Server and project URL you have set under web tab of project properties.

Comment: @Ekk: Here is what Project Url says: `http://localhost:55058/` the dropbox above says `IIS Express`

Comment: @Nikhil: This does not apply because a brand new ASP.NET MVC 4 project works on localhost as expected.

Comment: I also checked: a) destroying the workspace and deleting all the folders associated to the project and recreating workspace. b) calling `devenv.exe /resetsettings`: no way. c) copying the project on a VMachine with VStudio 2013 installed and I was able to debug on: `http://localhost:49688/`. Even more mysterious...

Comment: Changing the browser from IE to Google Chrome allows me to debug on `localhost`, so the problem is browser related.